# Question about the proof of the fact that minimum is attained for a l.s.c. convex function over a convex compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, maxima-minima

I quote here the proof of a result given in Haim Brezis *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and partial differential Equations*:

I haven't been able to conclude where exactly is this hypothesis used:

> A is closed and convex.

[image]

As far as I understand, one concludes the existence of minimum in the convex, closed and bounded set $\tilde{A}$, but this is done without using the fact that $A$ is closed and convex,

The fact that $\tilde{A}$ is closed  and convex simply follows from the lower semicontinuity and convexity of the function $\varphi$ and we obtain the existence of minimum in the set $\tilde{A}$ Then, as $\tilde{A} \subset A$ we obtain the minimum in the whole $A$.

Comment: the minimum in a small part can't prove that it will be the minimum in the whole set for example $\varphi=x$ on $\hat{A}=[1,2]$ and $A=[0,2]$

Comment: But $\tilde{A}$ cannot be that set. It would be necessarily $[0,2]$ in that case due to the definition of it.

Comment: I give this as remark to your last line but here everything is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the assumption for $A$ to be closed and convex are important, because if we put 
$$
B=\{x\in A \; , \; \varphi(x)\leq \varphi(a) \}
$$
so using the fact that $\varphi$ is lsc prove that $B$ is closed in the trace topology of $A$, since $A$ is closed $B$ is closed in $E$, and the fact that $A$ is convex and $\varphi$ is convex prove that $B$ is convex, and finally $(5)$ prove that $B$ is bounded  so in particular $B$ is a compact in $\sigma(E,E^*)$.

If $A$ is not closed the theorem will fall in fact :
$E=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=]0,+\infty[$ and $\varphi(t)=t$ it's clear that $\inf_{t\in A}\varphi(t)=0$ who is not achieved in any point of $A$.

If $A$ is closed but not convex the question is more complicated because every sci in a compact set achieve the minimum, so we need an infinite dimensional example,but the theorem fall also in this case in fact :
$E=l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $A=\{(x_n)_n\; , \; \sum_{k\geq0}|x_k|^2=1\}$ and $\varphi((x_n)_n)=x_1$ it's clear that $\inf_{x\in A}\varphi(x)=-\infty$ who is not achieved in any point of $A$.

Comment: Why do you consider the set $B$? $\varphi$ is defined on $A$, so then $\tilde{A}$ is closed and convex by lower semicontinuity and convexity of $\varphi$, and then compact in $\sigma(E, E^*)$. Then $\varphi$ attains its minimum on $\tilde{A}$, and as for every $x_0 \in C - \tilde{C}$ $\varphi(x) < \varphi(x_0)$, so it attains minimum at $C$. What is wrong with this argument? because I don't get it.

Comment: Can't we conclude without using the hypotesis I question from lsc and convexity that the set $\tilde{A}=\{x\in C \; , \; \varphi(x)\leq \varphi(a) \}$ is closed and convex? $\varphi$ is defined on $C$.

Comment: if your set $C$ is not convex $\hat A$ will be not necessary  convex think about $\varphi=x$ and $C=[0,1[\cup ]1,2]$

Comment: and the assumption that $C$ is closed is also important because using lsc we can proof that $\hat{A}$ is closed in the topology of $C$ (trace topology) only!!!, if you assume that $C$ closed  then every closed set in the topology of $C$ will be closed in the topology of $X$

Comment: i will edit the answer now

Comment: Thank you, that solved the question.