# A final step on the proof of $ f $is convex iff $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi \text { affine} \}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

**Let $f : \mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R} $

$f$ is convex if and only if $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi  \text { affine} \}$**

**In the proof of  ($\implies$), I have to follow the following hints:**

1. Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^M$ , and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $t < f (x)$ We claim that there exists an affine function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi \le f$ such that $\varphi(x) > t$; For this:

1a) Consider the point $P := (x, t)$. Prove that there exists a point $Q$ which minimizes the distance from $P$ to the graph of $f$

1b)Define the function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}$ as the affine function whose graph is the tangent plane to $\partial  B(P, |P − Q|)$ and passing by  $Q$

1c) Prove that $\varphi \le f$. Assume by contradiction that there exists a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $f (y) < \varphi(y)$. Let $A := (y, f (y))$. Prove that there exists a point $E$ on the graph of $f$ which is inside $B(P, r)$, $ r= |P − Q|$ contradicting the choice of $Q$

2. Conclude that f is the supremum of affine functions majorized by f .

---

I have already proven 1a) and 2)

1a) was proven here

[Finding a compact set where to use Weierstrass theorem with the distance function from a fixed point to the graph of a convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4698292/finding-a-compact-set-where-to-use-weierstrass-theorem-with-the-distance-functio/4698464?noredirect=1#comment9947509_4698464)

1b) I guess there is nothing to proof

I am having trouble proving the final part of 1c). I think it must be some continuity  (because $f$ convex $\implies f $ is continuous) or some geometrical argument that I can't figure out yet

---

**This is what I have so far in 1c)**

As told in the hint, assume by contradiction that

$ \exists y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $f (y) < \varphi(y) \tag{1}$

If  I can prove that $\exists $ a point $E \in$  the open ball $ B(P,r)$ s.t. $E \in G(f)$ (the graph of f) this would contradict the choice of  $Q$ because $E$ would be a point on G(f) at a
distance from $P$ less than that of $Q$ ($Q$ is on $\partial B(P,r)$) and $Q$ was supposed to be the point that minimizes the distance from $P$ to $G(f)$. I would then have a contradiction and $\varphi \le f$ would be proven.

So it suffices to prove that $\exists E \in B(P,r)$ s.t.  $E \in G(f)$.
Let $A=(y,f(y))\in G(f)$. Let's analyze 3 cases:$ A \in B(P,r), A \in \partial B(P,r)$ and $A \in {\overline B}^C(P,r)$

If $A \in B(P,r)$ I am done, just take $E=A$

If $A \in \partial B(P,r)$. Clearly $A \neq Q $. So the segment $\overline{AQ}$
would have distinct endpoints on $\partial B(P,r)$.

Let $Q=(y_Q,f(y_Q))$ and recall $P=(x,t)$ with $x,y_Q \in \mathbb{R}^M$. Lets use that $f(y)<\varphi(y)$, $f(y_Q)=\varphi(y_Q)$
Since $f$ is convex:  $ \forall \lambda \in [0,1]: f(z)= f(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)y_Q)\le \lambda f(y) +(1-y)f(y_Q) < \lambda \varphi(y)+(1-\lambda)\varphi(y_Q)=\varphi(\lambda y +(1-\lambda)y_Q)= \varphi(z)$

where in the last step I used the convexity of the affine function $\varphi$, which is actually an equality: So: $f(z) < \varphi (z)$, for all the $z=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)y_Q$ such that $(z, \lambda \varphi(y)+(1-\lambda)\varphi(y_Q))\in \overline{AQ}$.
This proves that there are points of $f$ below the segment $\overline{AQ}$, now I just have to prove that at least one of these $(z,f(z))$, with $\lambda \in (0,1)$ is inside the ball.

Here a 2-D sketch of the situation:

[image]

**This is where I am stuck,**

**1) Is everything OK so far ? and how do I prove that last part? I think it may be some continuity argument.**

**2) For the final case $A \in {\overline B}^C(P,r)$, I need to prove that the segment $\overline{AQ}$ intersects the sphere in some other point $A'$ besides $Q$, and then the thesis follows by using the previous result for the segment $\overline{A'Q}$. How do I prove that?**

Both of these results seem intuitive in 2 or 3 dimensions, but since we are in n dimensions, I am not so sure how to formalize them